# Inflated RecyclerView giving different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I've inflating a RecyclerView which has a NetoworkImageView and 2 Textview's. After inflating, I'm getting varaible sizes for row as seen in the image below.

How could I make them of fixed size?

[image]

This is the layout I'm inflating

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10">

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

This will keep your image to left and distributes rest of the space equally between two textviews.

If you want one textview large and one small change the weight from 1 to 0.7(small) and 0.3(large).

Comment: I tried this one too and I'm getting something similar like the one I've posted in the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Editted my code for alignment just use match parent width for textviews

Comment: It worked!! I had to edit the sizes but I got the idea for this. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

It will take occupy the both textview full size of width if there is text or not.

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting the only the time field improper. (I've posted the screenshot in the question)